# How to send query on submit and display results in prefilled form (React and react hook form)

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am using react js and react hook form to send a query to a node js backend which queries a database. I want to return the results of the query in a prefilled form. I am currently sending a request on submit and setting a useState value with the response. I then pass these values into the MemberUpdate function which uses them as default values. Currently the request goes through but I cannot get it to render.

Here i have the search function:

```
function MemberSearch() {
  
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  const {register, handleSubmit, formState: {errors} } = useForm({
    criteriaMode: "all"
  });

  const handleSearch = (e) => {

    fetch("http://localhost:3001/memberSearch", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(e),
      headers: { 'Content-type': "application/json"}
     }).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {setResults(data)})

  }

  const onSubmit = values => {handleSearch(values)}
  
  // Each input is provided and then followed by an ErrorMessage component
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <div>
            <h1>Member Management</h1>
            <h2>Search For a User</h2>
        </div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <br/>
          <label>Email: </label>
          <input type="text" name="email"
              {...register('email', {

                required: { value: true, message: "Missing Email"},
                maxLength: {value: 25, message: "Email cannot be more than 25 characters"},
                pattern: {value: /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
                          message: "Invalid Email format" }}
              )}/>
              <ErrorMessage 
                errors={errors}
                name="email"
                render={({messages}) => 
                  messages &&
                  Object.entries(messages).map(([type, message]) => (
                    <p class="error" key={type}>Error! {message}</p>
                  ))}/>
          <br></br><br/>
          <button>Search</button> 
          <br></br><br/>
      </form>

      {results ? <MemberUpdate values={results}/> : <div></div> }
    </div>

  );
}
```

Here is the first part of the MemberUpdate function which takes the values:

```
function MemberUpdate({values}){ 
  const {register, handleSubmit, formState: {errors} } = useForm({
    defaultValues: values
  });
```

Here is the back end:

```
app.post("/memberSearch",(req, res) => {
    
    console.log(req.body.email);
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE Email = " + mysql.escape(req.body.email);

    connection.query(sql, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(result);        
     });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be because `useForm` does not re-run when values prop is changed.

I think what you can do is manually reset the values of form using the reset/setValues and `useEffect()` to detect the state changes of values prop.

```
    function MemberUpdate({values}){ 
      const {register, handleSubmit, reset, formState: {errors} } = useForm();
      
      useEffect(() => {
        reset(values)
      }, [values])
    }
```